# Querying SharePoint farm for all lists of certain type

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I've created a list definition feature and in the elements.xml I've set its Type="111333". I've installed this list feature on several webs in my farm and created many lists from it. Is there an efficient way, maybe in CAML, to query my farm and retrieve only lists of this type (ServerTemplate = 111333) back? Thanks SF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) class to create a query that will search specific list types across all webs in an SPSite. The results are returned in a DataTable. This is probably the most effective way to query in Sharepoint. T

The sample in the documentation works both for 2007 and 2010 and queries all lists of type 105 (Contacts) accross all sites in the SiteCollection.

Comment: I'm just following the example you gave me, because u didnt have any problem to dow rate my answer because I wrote a same type of answer as you gave here. And worst than that you down rate the correct answer. So when you say to not assume the other guy is ignorance please think twice. And i really dont care if you are or not MVP, even an MVP doesnt know everything, and if he think it does is because he doesn't have enought knowledge.